# Android Studio: /dev/kvm device permission denied

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-14.04, kvm, android-studio-2.0, ubuntu-18.04

When I try to run my Android app on an emulator I get this error:

> /dev/kvm permission denied.

I checked the permissions and added the user I am currently logged in with to the kvm group. What is wrong?

Comment: Followed this approach and it worked, sudo chown <username> /dev/kvm  (This was on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS)

Answer (score 1057):

As mentioned in the comments, starting with **Ubuntu 18.04** and **Linux Mint Tara** you need to first `sudo apt install qemu-kvm`.

To check the ownership of `/dev/kvm` use

```
ls -al /dev/kvm
```

The user was `root`, the group `kvm`. To check which users are in the `kvm` group, use

```
grep kvm /etc/group
```

This returned

```
kvm:x:some_number:
```

on my system: as there is nothing rightwards of the final `:`, there are no users in the `kvm` group.

To **add your user to the kvm group**, you could use

```
sudo adduser $USER kvm
```

which adds the user to the group, and check once again with `grep kvm /etc/group`.

As mentioned by @marcolz, the command [`newgrp kvm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/newgrp) should change the group membership live for you. If that did not work, @Knossos mentioned that you might want to log out and back in (or restart), for the permissions to take effect. Or do as [@nmirceac mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300811/android-studio-dev-kvm-device-permission-denied/45749003?noredirect=1#comment107714346_45749003) and re-login in the same shell via `su - $USER`.

Comment: After install `qemu-kvm` and add my user to the group `kvm` it did not work. But it did after **restart** computer (Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: @rupj does the trick however google has just released a patch for linux version that also fixes libstd++ issues.

Comment: What if the user was `root` and the group was `root`. Should we change its group?

Comment: I had to everytime i turned on my pc
sudo chown -R username:username /dev/kvm

These steps saved my headache of everytime.
Thansk @serv-inc

This should be accepted as correct answer.

Comment: @slinstj Logging off and on again should be sufficient.

Comment: You can use this command to automatically add current user to kvm `sudo adduser $USER kvm`

Comment: @MichaelFulton: in that case, `sudo apt install qemu-kvm` should add the `kvm` group (edit)

Comment: @MichaelFulton I changed the user and group to my username. Then added my username to the group. Works.

Comment: You might need to log out and back in AND restart Android Studio to see the change, for me, the 'refresh' button in the AVD manager didn't seem to refresh the permissions

Comment: I needed grant ownership of kvm to user too:  `sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm `

Comment: I don't know but this command worked for me to add user to the kvm usergroup: sudo usermod -a -G kvm seocliff

Comment: @sdlins to just logout and back in does the job too.

Comment: if you don't want to logout or restar, simply do 
  sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm 
as described by @IvánRodríguezTorres

Comment: If you don't want to log out, use `newgrp kvm` as that will check your group membership like if you were logging in.

Comment: For updating an existing user, it is probably best to use 
`usermod -aG kvm $USER`

Also in my case (Ubuntu 18.04) I had to add the kvm group first.

Comment: don't chown it - most orthodox way is to refresh the groups - "su - $USER" as the user - and then check everything with the command `id`

Comment: @sdlins A reboot/logout isn't strictly necessary. You can also do `su - $USER`, which refreshes the group assignment in that particular shell (i.e., you'll have to launch Android Studio from that shell).

Comment: Works with me only need to reboot.

Comment: it's warned by Android studio itself you should logout and login to make changes take effect.

Answer (score 646):

This is how I got it to work in **Ubuntu 18.04**

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

Add your user to kvm group using:

```
sudo adduser <Replace with username> kvm
```

If still showing *permission denied*:

```
sudo chown <Replace with username> /dev/kvm
```

Try it.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too. I didn't have to perform the last step because my permissions were set to: `crw-rw---- 1 root kvm 10, 232 Jul 27 15:32 /dev/kvm` (so once I added my user to the kvm group, it just worked).

Comment: step 2 might require a reboot

Comment: Do I need to reboot OS?

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04.1! @NikolayBaranenko is not necessary

Comment: this helped me in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked for me on Mint 19.1 after reboot

Comment: It works like charm, especially the last command you mentioned. I did not even need to restart IDE or OS.

Comment: you should not change the ownership of `/dev/kvm/` folder. instead you should add the user to `kvm` group as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/1213934

Comment: this worked for me on ubuntu 18.04 I had to do all the steps,I rebooted android studio after step 2

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @JakobEriksson It requires one to re-login. Reboots are reserved for Windows (and systemd updates) ;-)

Comment: If I close my device and try to restart it, it wont work unless I do `sudo chown <Replace with username> /dev/kvm` again

Comment: It worked with Linux Mint 19 Tricia, XFCE, without a reboot

Comment: Yes just as @logoff has suggested, you shouldn't change the ownership of /dev/kvm, because doing that you break the Default ACL of your Linux system, which is not a good security practice. Follow this instruction instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/7206497

Comment: How would one adapt this solution outside of Ubuntu 18.04? I don't even have the qemu-kvm package on Elementary OS, which is based on Ubuntu. I think it's better not to install an additional package.

Comment: It worked for me just need to restart the system after instructions

Answer (score 53):

Try this, it worked for me:

1. `sudo apt install qemu-kvm`
2. `sudo chown -R <username>:<username> /dev/kvm`

Comment: You might need to relogin for it to take effect.

Comment: This is questionable, since it treats a multiuser system as a single user system. No other user will be able to use KVM when following this approach. Is that a good idea? I doubt it...

Comment: This solution is plain wrong as it modifies the default rights to /dev/kvm. It's not just that it will not persist between reboots / system updates. It also forcefully modifies system settings. Stay away.

Comment: Don't do the `chown` - add your username to the proper groups - kvm or libvirt. See the documentation for [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation](Ubuntu).

Comment: Why do you chown a device file recursively? Also, what's with the `–` suffix? This surely yields an error.

Answer (score 38):

This is because `/dev/kvm` is not accessible. To make is accessible from android studio run the below command

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm
```

It will ask for your password. After that restart Android Studio.

`KVM` is required to rum emulator. If you have not install it yet then install it

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

Comment: This answer did the trick in my case after following the most upvoted answer! Thanks!

Comment: Do not do that. See my answer above.

Comment: @andrzejwp: What answer? I don't see any answer from you. Given how adamant you are about your answer, can you **link to it**?

Comment: Why do you recursively (`-R`) change the permissions on a single device file? Also, the execute permissions are superfluous. Finally, udev may adjust the permissions after each emulator start.

Answer (score 32):

Have you also tried following, it should work:

```
sudo chown <username> /dev/kvm
sudo chmod o+x /dev/kvm
```

Comment: `chmod o+x` is completely useless. The first command make it work - but see my other comments way down why this is a bad idea.

Comment: This works but does not persist a reboot. I am on POP OS though!

Comment: This solution is plaing wrong as it modifies the default rights to `/dev/kvm`. It's not just that it will not persist between reboots / system updates. It also forcefuly modifies system settings. Stay away.

Comment: This is not persistent over reboots. The udev daemon might re-adjust the permissions during its runtime and given others the executable permission bit is simply superfluous.

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm
```

Simply running that one command worked for me here in September 2019 running:

> Description:  Ubuntu 18.04.3
>
> LTS Release: 18.04
>
> Codename: bionic

Comment: Do not do that. See my answer above.

Comment: @andrzejwp Where is your answer?  Is it in a comment?  If it is, it is probably collapsed and I can't see it. I've searched the page for your user tag, but can't find. I am happy to try your answer out -- because my answer isn't quite right (doesn't persist) -- but I cannot find it.  Leave a link or create a new answer and I'll try it.

Comment: @andrzejwp: please link to your answers, instead of saying "above". What if your answer ends up below the one you're commenting on?

Comment: This is not persistent over reboots and the udev daemon may readjust the ownership of `/dev/kvm` during its runtime.

Answer (score 29):

**Step 1:** (Install qemu-kvm)

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

**Step 2:** (Add your user to kvm group using)

```
sudo adduser username kvm
```

**Step 3:** (If still showing permission denied)

```
sudo chown username /dev/kvm
```

**Final step:**

```
ls -al /dev/kvm
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003471/427158) of [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61345425/427158) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61767283/427158).

Answer (score 28):

Under Ubuntu, the permissions of `/dev/kvm` usually look like this:

```
$ ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw---- 1 root kvm 10, 232 May 24 09:54 /dev/kvm
```

The user that runs the Android emulator (i.e. your user) needs to get access to this device.

Thus, there are basically 2 ways how to get access:

- Make sure that your user is part of the kvm group (requires a re-login of your user after the change)
- Widen the permissions of that device such that your user has access (requires a change to the udev daemon configuration)

### Add User to KVM Group

Check if your user is already part of the kvm group, e.g.:

```
$ id 
uid=1000(juser) gid=1000(juser) groups=1000(juser),10(wheel)
```

If it isn't then add it with e.g.:

```
$ sudo usermod --append --groups kvm juser
```

After that change you have to logout and login again to make the group change effective (check again with `id`).

### Widen Permissions

Alternatively, you can just can widen the permissions of the `/dev/kvm` device.

Example:

```
echo 'KERNEL=="kvm", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0666", OPTIONS+="static_node=kvm"' \
    | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/99-kvm4all.rules
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger --name-match=kvm
```

FWIW, this is the default on other distributions such as Fedora and CentOS.

Check the effectiveness of the above commands with another `ls`. You should see output similar to:

```
$ ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root kvm 10, 232 2020-05-16 09:19 /dev/kvm
```

Big advantage: You don't need to logout and login again for this change to be effective.

### Non-Solutions

- calling `chmod` and `chown` directly on `/dev/kvm` - 1) these changes aren't persistent over reboots and 2) since `/dev/kvm` permissions are controlled by the udev daemon, it can 'fix' its permissions at any time, e.g. after each emulator run
- adding executable permissions to `/dev/kvm` - your emulator just requires read and write permissions
- changing permissions recursively on `/dev/kvm` - I don't know what's up with that - looks like cargo cult
- installing extra packages like qemu - you already have your emulator installed - you just need to get access to the `/dev/kvm` device

Comment: An amazing solution, not only it does *not* require relogin, but also explains why most other solutions have unneeded steps or are plain flawed. +1!

Comment: Thank you. It worked, and you also explained WHY and HOW it works.

Answer (score 24):

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I was facing the same problem. I run this piece of command in terminal and problem is resolved.

```
sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm
```

the above command is for all the user present in your system.

If you want to give access to only a specific user then run this command

```
sudo chown UserNameHere /dev/kvm
```

Comment: No. This is not something you should do. See my answer above.

Comment: How is this answer different from @raddevus' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57937547/427158) which he posted one month earlier?

Answer (score 21):

### Here is a simple solution

#### open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo groupadd -r kvm
```

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/60-qemu-system-common.rules
```

Add the following line to the opened file and save it

> KERNEL=="kvm", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0660"

Finally run:

```
sudo usermod -a -G kvm <your_username>
```

Reboot your PC and Done!

Comment: This is bad advice. Never directly edit udev configuration under `/lib/udev/rules.d`. Udev has an overlay mechanism where configuration placed in `/etc/udev/rules.d` has priority over one available under `/lib/udev/rules.d`.

Comment: I'm not a professional Linux user, It's just a solution that worked for me and I decide to make it succinct and easy to read for others like me. thank you for your clarification, Max.

Comment: @NasirJafarzadeh: so why not edit your answer to create that override at `/etc/udev/rules.d` instead of editing `/lib/udev/rules.d`? That's what Gerd suggests, by the way.

Answer (score 20):

There's absolutely no need to install `qemu-kvm` (and all its dependencies) if you only want to run the Android Studio Emulator.

The only thing you have to do is to give your user (i.e. the one you are logged in with) the right to access the `/dev/kvm`-device.

This is done in three simple steps.

**First:**

Create the `kvm`-group

`groupadd -r kvm`

The option `-r` creates a system group, i.e. with a GID <= 999 (see `/etc/login.defs` => `SYS_GID_MAX`)

**Second:**

Change permissions on `/dev/kvm`. This could be done as part of the `qemu-kvm`-installation, because one of the dependencies is installing `qemu-system-common` (on current Ubuntu systems, package name may vary), which in turn installs the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-qemu-system-common.rules` containing the following:

```
KERNEL=="kvm", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0660"
```

So if you are just create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-qemu-permissions.rules` containing the above line, you are done with the first step.

**Third:**

Add your username to the group by executing

`usermod -a -G kvm <your_username>` - the `-a` is important for **adding** your user to the kvm-group. Without that you will overwrite the group-settings for your user to only belonging to "kvm"...

That's it.

For the new udev rule and group setting to take effect it's easiest to reboot and login again.

You can also execute

`udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`

for reloading the rules but you still have to logout and login again with regard to the new group.

Comment: Btw, +1 for pointing out that installing `qemu-kvm` is _completely unnecessary_ for Android Studio. **This is the best answer**

Answer (score 14):

I countered the same problem and to solve this issue just type the following commands in terminal for Linux clients

```
   sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm

    // type your password

   sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm
```

and after that try running simulator it'll work

Comment: God, no. See my comments above.

Comment: Superfluous install of qemu-kvm, superfluous use of recursive option and superfluously sets executive permission. Also non persistent over reboots and even during runtime of udev.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rwx /dev/kvm
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Way better than all the `chown` examples here, but I would omit the `x` from the permissions.

Comment: Change isn't not persistent over reboots.

Answer (score 6):

I am using linux debian, and i am facing the same way. In my **AVD** showing me a message "/dev/kvm permission denied" and i tried to find the solution, then what i do to solve it is, in terminal type this :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/kvm
```

it will grant an access for folder /dev/kvm,then check again on your **AVD** , the error message will disappear, hope it will help.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Do not do that, ever. See my comments above.

Comment: @andrzejwp: comments above, WHERE?!

Comment: Recursive option is superfluous, execution permissions are superfluous. Change not persistent over reboots. Change not stable during udev runtime.

Answer (score 3):

This Worked For Me on Linux (x18)  ☑  Hope It Will Work For You Aswell

```
sudo chown hp /dev/kvm
```

Comment: No it wont, and please do not do that.

Comment: Change is not persistent over reboots.

Answer (score 3):

Just one slight improvement on [Jerrin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4387357/jerin-a-mathews) answer on fixing this error with Ubuntu 18.04 by utilizing `$USER` variable available in the bash terminal. So you could use the following commands two commands:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

Add the current user to the kvm group

```
sudo adduser $USER kvm
```

Also if you are still having issues, one other problem for me was the way in which I installed Ubuntu. I made the mistake of checking the box during installation for installing 3rd party software which did not play nice with my nvidia graphics card for development. So I reinstalled Ubuntu with this third party software **unchecked**.

[image]

Then after installation, open up Software & Updates and go to the Additional Drivers tab. Select the most up to date proprietary drivers that have also been tested and apply changes. Should restart the machine for the changes to take affect.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What finally fixed it for me on Ubuntu 18.04 was:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
sudo adduser $USER kvm
sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Jerin A Mathews'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51003471/427158).

Answer (score 1):

1. I tried `sudo setfacl -m u:UserName:rwx /dev/kvm` . and it works .
2. In the android studio you need to change : tools> avd manager >(chose the pen to edit your device and change 'graphics' from automatic to software ) to avoid emulator drawable error

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

```
user@user:~$ whoami
```

*antonio*

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm

sudo adduser antonio kvm

sudo chown antonio /dev/kvm
```

*last but not least*

On Android studio
select File -> Restart IDE

to apply the changes

Then create the emulator

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation with the same error of permissions on /dev/kvm
I had done the necessary installations but not added the user to the kvm group
All I had to do was

```
sudo adduser <Replace with username> kvm
```

and ofcourse DON'T forget to restart your Ubuntu instance.

Comment: Isn't logout/login enough?

Comment: @user1053510 After adding a user to a group there's no need to reboot (even after 3.5 years ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

**/dev/kvm** permission denied android studio

[Motherboard]Set VT(Virtualization Technology) in BIOS and install Virtual Machine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo usermod -aG kvm $USER
newgrp kvm
```

-aG option is to add Current $USER to group kvm

newgrp kvm is to switch current user group to kvm group. so the user will have the kvm related permission.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I got this error after updating my ubuntu to 18.04.1. I just download new system image for emulator or you can say that download new emulator and it is worked for me.

Comment: This won't change anything regarding the original problem with `/dev/kvm`-permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Open Terminal and log as admin

```
sudo su
```

Go to the dev folder

```
cd /dev/
```

Change the kvm mode

```
chmod 777 -R kvm
```

Comment: I think you mean `cd /dev` instead of sudo.

Comment: yeah, cd /dev .

Comment: This works. But have to do this every time computer restarts.

Comment: Why do you call `chmod` with `-R`? Recursively changing the permissions on a single device file `/dev/kvm` doesn't look too useful. Also, execute permissions are superfluous on that device. Finally, udev may readjust the `/dev/kvm` permissions after each run. Thus, this method isn't very effective.

Answer (score -1):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm -y
sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm
```

Answer (score -1):

Although KVM is a module built into the Linux kernel itself, it doesn't mean that all the necessary packages are included in your Ubuntu/Linux install by default. You'll need a few to get started, and they can be installed with this command in the terminal:

```
& sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils virt-manager
```

**Configure the network bridge**

In order for your virtual machines to access your network interface and be assigned their own IP addresses, we need to configure bridged networking on our system.

First, run the following Linux command in order to find out what name your network interface has been assigned. Knowing this will allow us to do additional configuration later.

```
$ ip a
```

[image: Determine name of network interface]

In my case, the network interface is called `enp2s0`. Yours will likely be very similarly named.

In order to tell Ubuntu that we want our connection to be bridged, we'll need to edit the network interfaces configuration file. Doing this won't negatively impact your connection at all. It'll just allow that connection to be shared with the VMs.

Use `code` (Visual Studio Code) or your favorite text editor to open the following file:

```
$ code /etc/network/interfaces
```

When you first open this file, it may be empty or contain just a couple of lines. Your bridge interface is called `br0`, so add the following line for the interface to come up by default:

```
auto br0
```

Below this line, add the following line for your current network interface (the one who's named you determined earlier).

```
iface enp2s0 inet manual
```

Next, you can add the bridge information. These lines tell Ubuntu that your bridge will use DHCP for automatic IP address assignment, and your bridge will manage your current interface.

```
iface br0 inet dhcp
      bridge_ports enp2s0
```

This is how your file should look once all the changes have been applied (if you also have a couple of lines that were already there, it's fine to have them too):

[image: Network interfaces configuation file]

Save your changes and exit the file.

**Add your user to the groups**

In order to manage your virtual machine(s) without root privileges, your user will need to belong to two user groups. Run the following commands to add your user to the appropriate groups (replacing user1 with the name of your user):

```
$ sudo adduser user1 libvirt
$ sudo adduser user1 libvirt-qemu
$ sudo adduser user1 kvm
```

When you're done, you should restart your system to ensure that all of the changes done to your user and network configuration have a chance to take effect.

Comment: Downvote: This thread isn't about getting KVM to work. It's just about omitting a "permission denied" message while starting the Emulator packaged with Andoid Studio. No need for `libvirt` and no need for configuring interfaces...

Comment: While I'm very new to Android development, I bet it does most of these steps for you. It does ask you to [install many of the same packages](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration?utm_source=android-studio#vm-linux-kvm), though. (Expecting every Android developer to properly set up a bridge is a bit in left field, even limited to *Linux* Android developers.)

Answer (score -2):

In order to make a virtual device in Linux - I have to follow this three command and it helps me to avoid trouble for building avd devices - the process are -

```sh
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
sudo adduser $USER kvm
sudo chown $USER /dev/kvm
```

so, now you are good to go, restart android studio and start building application with emulator.

Comment: Duplicate of [James Hooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61345425/427158).

Answer (score -3):

Provide appropriate permissions with this command

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm
```

Comment: See also my comments to a similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300811/android-studio-dev-kvm-device-permission-denied#comment109628944_55546477

Comment: It worked for me

Answer (score -5):

Running the below command in Ubuntu 18.04 worked for me
sudo chown -R  /dev/kvm

Comment: First: Never change ownership of system files --- 
Second: As `/dev/kvm` is a file `-R` has no effect --- 
Third: `chown` needs a `new owner` argument --- 
Fourth: After rebooting you have to do this again and again.

Answer (score -10):

If you open your ide with sudo. You are not going to have this problem.

Comment: why on earth I need sudo permissions to develop an android app?

Comment: Emphasizing again: one must never do this. Also look into gksu and gksudo for running GUI apps as root.