# Android emulator failed to start on Arch Linux, always bootloop

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, qemu, archlinux, kvm

I have Arch Linux installed on my laptop, I installed Android studio too. 
From this system I can almost develop anything I want

But I cannot boot android emulator either hardware accelerate or not.

When I get the emulator updated to the latest, it keep showing me the following message

```
Emulator: KVM: injection failed, MSI lost (Operation not permitted)
```

and I have no idea what's it talking about.

[image]

Comment: How did you installed the android studio? through zip file?

Comment: using Archlinux aur https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install `qemu` if not install

```
sudo packman -S qemu

sudo adduser $USER kvm
```

Then close the android studio and logout and log back in.
After that open the android studio and open the emulator.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/7356355

Comment: emm...there is no package named qemu-kvm, but got one named "qemu" https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qemu/

Comment: install it then

Comment: it doesn't work and when I shutdown the emulator it showing "handshake failed"

Comment: "emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
Warning: restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading.
^Cemulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 71531 ms
[3561:3743:1207/213645.959406:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1050)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101"

Comment: I wipe it out and recreate avd again, then it works!

Comment: glad it worked, I am using Linux Mint I thought qemu might be the issue since I also faced a kvm permission issue, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/7356355) fixed my issue. So I modified it for your needs.. I added a reference to that answer in my answer.