# Why does Android Studio swap the ownership of dev/kvm?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, linux-mint, chown

I tried to configure a simulated device in Android Studio under Configure -> AVD manager. It alerted me during the creation process that the current user did not have access to dev/kvm, so I changed the ownership of that directory useing `chown <username> dev/kvm`. After that, I was able to create/run the simulated device, but then I ran into another problem.

After I close the simulated device, it won't run again, and trying to run it throws a "failed to start" error. If I go back to my terminal and type `chown username dev/kvm` again, then I can start the simulated device again. It seems that Linux is changing the ownership of that directory whenever I close the simulator.

Is there any way to prevent it from doing this, so I don't have to type that into the terminal every time?

Comment: Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749003/3789527), might have some helpful information.